# session_id in codeigniter returns nothing

Tags: codeigniter

My `CI_VERSION` is `3.0.6`.

now I want to echo `session_id`, but it returns nothing!

```
class MainIndex extends BaseController
{


    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function index()
    {
        $this->library->load('session');
        echo  $this->session->userdata('session_id');
        return ;

...
```

my config:

```
$config['sess_driver']          = 'files';
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'soheil/files_cache/';
$config['sess_valid_drivers']    = array();
$config['sess_cookie_name']    = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 68400;
$config['sess_expire_on_close']   = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']      = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_match_ip']          = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent']   = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 68500;
```

Comment: Just to be sure session_start(); is added. Right?

Comment: have you stored anything in session  ? show us that code

Answer (score 0):

Try to print all session data using.

Also make sure that you have loaded session in config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');

print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

also in order to use the session you are require to add some string in `$config['encryption_key']`

Answer (score 0):

Just having a read in the Codeigniter user guide, it makes mention that session_id is no longer available via the sessions library since "sometime ago" (My Words, not theirs...)

The alternative they recommend is `session_id()`.

Give that a shot!